# Improving the performance of sequence

Tags: .net, f#, primes

I am implementing two versions of Eratosthenes's Sieve, the first one is imperative:

```
let primesUntilArray n =
    let isqrt x =
        let mutable root = 0UL
        let mutable p = 1UL <<< 31

        while p > 0UL do
            while x < (root + p) * (root + p) do
                p <- p >>> 1

            root <- root + p
            p <- p >>> 1

        root

    let isPrime = Array.create (int <| n + 1) true
    let bound = int <| isqrt (uint64 n)

    let mutable i = 2

    while i <= bound do
        if isPrime.[i] then
            let mutable j = i * i

            while j <= n do
                isPrime.[j] <- false
                j <- j + i

        i <- i + 1

    let mutable primes = []
    let mutable i = 2

    while i <= n do
        if isPrime.[i] then
            primes <- i :: primes

        i <- i + 1

    List.rev primes
```

while the second one is functional (with F#'s sequence):

```
let primesUntilSequence n =
    let rec pickPrimes s =
        let sieveWith p =
            Seq.filter (fun n -> n < p * p || n % p <> 0)

        let p = Seq.head s

        seq {
            yield p
            yield! pickPrimes (sieveWith p (Seq.tail s))
        }

    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 2)
    |> pickPrimes
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun p -> p <= n)
    |> Seq.toList
```

The time complexity of both is about [`O(n log log n)`](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/sieve-of-eratosthenes.html), but the performance of the version using sequence is very bad, e.g.

```sh
> primesUntilArray 9000 |> List.length |> printfn "%d";;
1117
Real: 00:00:00.004, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC Gen0: 1, Gen1: 0, Gen2: 0
val it: unit = ()

> primesUntilSequence 9000 |> List.length |> printfn "%d";;
1117
Real: 00:00:15.388, CPU: 00:00:15.375, GC Gen0: 592, Gen1: 64, Gen2: 0
val it: unit = ()
```

That means about 4000 times slower in generating primes until 9000. How can I improve the performance of the second one?

*Thank you all.
Following is a slightly modified version of the solution of @Tomas Petricek*

```
let primesUntilList n =
    let rec pickPrimes ps xs =
        let sieveWith p =
            List.filter (fun n -> n < p * p || n % p <> 0)

        match xs with
        | p :: xs' ->
            if p * p > n then
                (List.rev xs) @ ps
            else
                pickPrimes (p :: ps) (sieveWith p xs')
        | _ -> ps

    List.rev <| pickPrimes [] [ 2..n ]
```

This list based version is still about two times less efficient than using array, but much better than my initial sequence based version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your sequence-based version is that deconstructing a sequence using `Seq.head` and `Seq.tail` recursively is very inefficient. The sequence returned by `Seq.tail` iterates the original sequence, but skips the first element. This means that by applying `Seq.tail` recursively, you are creating more and more sequences (I guess this is O(N^2)) that you need to iterate over.

This gets much more efficient if you use a list, where pattern matching against `x::xs` simply takes a reference to the next cons cell:

```
let primesUntilList n =
  let rec pickPrimes s =
      let sieveWith p =
          List.filter (fun n -> n < p * p || n % p <> 0)
      match s with 
      | [] -> []
      | p::ps -> p :: pickPrimes (sieveWith p ps)

  [ 2 .. n ] |> pickPrimes
```

This is still less efficient than the array-based version (and I think that is to be expected), but it does not perform as badly as your sequence-based version.

Comment: Excellent analysis, thank you. I didn't recognize that `Seq.tail` is about `O(n)`. I believe your guess is correct, the total overhead of recursive `Seq.tail` is then about `O(n^2 / log n)` (since there would be about `n / log n` recursive call.

Answer (score 4):

[`Seq.cache`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#cache) is useful when you want to evaluate a sequence multiple times (which is effectively what `Seq.tail` is doing). You can drop it into your original code like this:

```ml
let primesUntilSequence n =
    let rec pickPrimes s =
        let sieveWith p =
            Seq.filter (fun n -> n < p * p || n % p <> 0)

        let s = Seq.cache s   // *** cache the sequence ***
        let p = Seq.head s

        seq {
            yield p
            yield! pickPrimes (sieveWith p (Seq.tail s))
        }

    Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i + 2)
    |> pickPrimes
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun p -> p <= n)
    |> Seq.toList
```

On my box, `primesUntilSequence 9000` now runs in about a quarter of a second.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your analysis is precise, I've thought that `Seq.tail` is `O(1)`, but it is not. I didn't know about `Seq.cache`; if I understand it correctly `let s = Seq.cache s` helps each element of the sequence evaluated only one time, though `Seq.tail s` still needs to skip elements but it does not need to recalculated skipped elements?

Comment: Your solution, the one of @Tomas Petricek (and the array version also) needs memory to stored generated elements. My naive idea initially is using sequence to implement a "zero allocated memory" version of Sieve of Erastothenes.

Comment: Yes, `Seq.cache` allows `Seq.tail` to skip an element without having to recalculate the sequence. This is a classic [time-space tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with sequence performance issues, it can be helpful to work with them imperatively inside sequence expressions. In short, Bring Your Own Enumerator.

This is still horribly inefficient, compared to both the `array` and `list` approaches. At least you have full control over the allocation of the resources the nested sequences require.

```
type IEnumerator<'a> =
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<'a>
let primesUntilIterator n =
    let sieveWith p (en : IEnumerator<_>) = seq{ 
        while en.MoveNext() do
            let n = en.Current
            if n < p * p || n % p <> 0 then
                yield n }
    let rec pickPrimes (s : seq<_>) = seq{
        use en = s.GetEnumerator()
        if en.MoveNext() then
            let p = en.Current
            yield p
            yield! pickPrimes (sieveWith p en) }

    { 2..n } |> pickPrimes
```